# Trying to reference text from a JTextField when clicking on a JButton

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, actionlistener

I have (basically) the following code

```
JTextField input = new JTextField(20);
JButton calculate = new JButton("calculate");
calculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        String test = new String(input.getText());

        }
});
```

and basically my goal is to do something with the text from the textfield "input" when the button is clicked. However I get

"Cannot refer to the non-final local variable input defined in an enclosing scope"

How do I access the text in "input" when the button is clicked, without this error?

Comment: Have your class implement ActionListener, and set calculate.addActionListener(this); instead.

Comment: `JTextField input = new JTextField(20);JButton calculate = new JButton("calculate");`  are those code inside any method.?

Answer (score 3):

You could mark the `input` field as `final`, for example

```
final JTextField input = new JTextField(20);
JButton calculate = new JButton("calculate");
calculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    String test = input.getText();
});
```

But I'd prefer to make the field an instance field, but that's me.  See [Understanding Class Memembers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) for more details

Answer (score 2):

I guess your field declaration inside some method.

Make  these declaration  in the class scope. Not in any method like constructor or others.

Declare them as a class property as like:

```
JTextField input;
JButton calculate;
```

then initialize them where you want to

```
input = new JTextField(20);
calculate = new JButton("calculate");
```

If you want to keep that `JTextField input` as local variable then you have to make it final to get access from the `ActionListener`.